# How to hide date in elementary top bar?

Tags: wingpanel

I just want to display the hour, because It looks more clean, this option was removed and I can't find a way to just hide the day/date from the options, even elemetary-tweaks cant do that, do you guys know where is the file that contains the code of this ?, maybe I can change it by myself

Answer (score 1):

You can download the indicator source with

```
apt source wingpanel-indicator-datetime
```

I would start at the source file `src/Widgets/PanelLabel.vala`: it seems that removing (all occurences of) the `date_label` variable does the trick.

After you can build and  install the package

```
debuild -us -uc
sudo dpkg --install ../wingpanel-indicator-datetime*.deb
```

Comment: I commented inline 54`/// this.add (date_label);`
I think will work but how I compile this? or add to the system?

Comment: I think that you should ask a new question: how to compile a (debian) package? :)

Answer (score 0):

clone the component:

```
git clone https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-datetime.git
```

as of 5.1 (Hera), I followed @Egon Stetmann's lead and commented out in src/Widgets/PanelLabel.vala:

```
//        add (date_revealer);
```

per @lemonslice's suggestion, follow these [instructions to compile and install changes to Elementary](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/23914/20912).

voila!  enjoy not having to stare at a date all day! :)